# Mathieu Functions References

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, special-functions, mathematical-physics

I came across the Mathieu functions when solving a PDE with Mathematica.

My solution was of the form $f=C_1Mat_C + C_2 Mat_S$

AFAIK those are the non periodical Mathieu functions, which are different from the periodic ones (Cos-elliptic and Sin-elliptic).

What i was looking for is a reference with an extensive treatment of both periodic and non periodic Mathieu functions, covering their properties and with some applicative examples (i come from the physics community).

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked in [Abramowitz and Stegun](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Handbook_of_Mathematical_Functions/KiPCAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Abramowitz+Stegun&printsec=frontcover)?  Also try McLachlan, N. W., [Theory and Applications of Mathieu Functions](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Theory_and_Applications_of_Mathieu_Funct/_apo0AEACAAJ?hl=en)

Comment: Note that Abramowitz and Stegun have been superseded by the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/28).

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but probably worth checking out (based on Corless's coauthorship and the high quality of papers published in SIAM Review): Chris Brimacombe, Robert M. Corless, and Mair Zamir, "Computation and Applications of Mathieu Functions: A Historical Perspective", *SIAM Review*, Vol. 63, No. 4, pp. 653-720 (open access).

Comment: Robert M. Corless, "Special Functions in Problem Solving Environments: A personal view", *Maple Transactions*, Vol. 3, No. 2, Article 15927, August 2023. 30 pp. ([online](https://mapletransactions.org/index.php/maple/article/download/15927/12354)): "This paper discusses some of the philosophical and historical underpinnings of the talk “The Mathieu Functions: Computational and Historical Perspectives” given at the Maple Conference 2022. [...] The talk “The Mathieu Functions: ...” that I gave at the Maple Conference 2022 was based in large part on the paper [8], which is available open-access."